# Use .bashrc without breaking sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, bashrc

My problem is that I need to set a few variables, and output a few lines every time I login to the ssh shell, and at the same time I have to be able to use sftp to tarnsfer files via Filezilla.

Now, as per the openssh FAQ at [http://www.openssh.org/faq.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114130008/http://www.openssh.com:80/faq.html#2.9), if your startup scripts echo any kind of output, it messes up with sftp. So it either delays indefinitely, or errors out with a "Connection closed by server with exit code 128".

I have tried solutions like moving .bashrc to .bash_profile, or using the following code in .bashrc:

```
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]
then
   source .bashc_real
fi
```

And:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]
then
   source .bashc_real
fi
```

However, nothing works. My shell terminal is bash, and I connect to sftp with filezilla.

Comment: This is also important when you're using an IDE like PyCharm, which (might) use SFTP for remote-host file editing. Took me a while to figure out why one remote-box worked, and another broke.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try doing this instead

```
if [ "$SSH_TTY" ]
then
   source .bashc_real
fi
```

Comment: This worked the best in the following scenarios: sftp, ssh and switch to another user, sudo su from that other user back to me.

Answer (score 18):

Mike's answer will probably work.  But it's worth pointing out that you can accomplish this carefully selecting which startup files to put the verbose stuff in.  From the bash man page:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  commands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash reads
> and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This may be
> inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file  option will  force
> bash  to  read  and  execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

The sftp/scp tools start an interactive non-login shell, so .bashrc will be sourced.  Many distributions source .bashrc from .bash_profile or vice versa, so it can get confusing.  A good trick for testing the cleanliness of your login environment is to ssh in with a command, which simulates the same way scp/sftp connect.  For example: `ssh myhost /bin/true` will show you exactly what scp/sftp sees when they connect.

A simple demo:

```
insyte@mazer:~$ echo "echo Hello from .profile" > .profile
insyte@mazer:~$ echo "echo Hello from .bashrc" > .bashrc

sazerac:~ insyte$ ssh mazer /bin/true
Hello from .bashrc
sazerac:~ insyte$

insyte@mazer:~$ rm .bashrc

sazerac:~ insyte$ ssh mazer /bin/true
sazerac:~ insyte$
```

The first test will cause scp/sftp/rsync etc. to break.  The second version will work just fine.

Comment: I don't agree that *"The sftp/scp tools start an **interactive** non-login shell"* as we cannot really **interact** with the shell. But I don't understand why `.bashrc` would be source'd for `scp` or `ssh host command`.

Comment: The term "interactive" isn't subjective. It's a term used by bash to describe one of its startup modes. It is a fact that sftp/scp start an "interactive non-login shell". Feel free to argue with the developers about whether not sourcing .bashrc is appropriate in this case; I'm just telling you what it does.

Comment: `Bash` invoked by `scp` or `ssh host command` is indeed **non-interactive**. I just found this in bash manual: *"Bash attempts to determine **when it is being run with its standard input
       connected to a network connection**, as when executed by the remote shell
       daemon,  usually **rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd**.  If bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and  executes  commands
       from  `~/.bashrc`,  if  that file exists and is readable."* Here is the [interesting history](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-06/msg00028.html).

Comment: Also see the section *Remote non login non interactive shells* in [this wiki page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using csh:

```csh
if ($?prompt)
  ... interactive stuff ...
```

And if it's bash:

```bash
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
  ... interactive stuff ...
fi
```

or alternatively using bash regular expressions:

```bash
if [[ $- =~ i ]]; then
  ... interactive stuff ...
fi
```

These lines should precede lines where you ouput/echo something back.

Comment: Hi, could you explain the code, please. I know that $? is the return level of the previous command. I dont understand $?prompt and $-, though. Or is csh specific?

Comment: @Droidzone: `$?var` in `csh` returns 1 if `var` is defined and 0 otherwise. `$-` in `bash` would has the `i` char in its value if the shell is interactive.

Comment: Should update answer to explain $- is a special variable of shell options.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables

Answer (score 1):

Mike's solution worked for me as well. But since my default shell is TCSH, I had to slightly edit the fix as follows (in .tcshrc):

```
if ( $?SSH_TTY ) then
    exec /bin/bash
endif
```

Just thought I would share for everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first lines of my (default) `.bashrc` file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

The check for an interactive session avoids messing up with SCP, SFTP or `ssh remote-host command` mode.

Without this, if your file `.bashrc` uses `echo` or some other stuff printing on stdout, you may get this kind of errors:

- SFTP : `Received message too long 168435779`
- SCP : `protocol error: unexpected <newline>`

Answer (score 0):

I like some of the other solutions mentioned here better, but I thought I throw out the solution that I currently use on my bash and csh VMs to prevent SFTP disconnects due to echo commands in my startup scripts, just in case anyone finds the information helpful.

In BASH:

```
if [ $TERM == "xterm" ] || [ $TERM == "xterm-256color" ]; then
  echo "Xterm display identified: echo enabled"
  echo_disable="0"
else
  echo_disable="1"
fi

# Use the following for all subsequent echo commands
if [ $echo_disable == 0 ]; then
 echo "Safe to display on Xterm"
fi
```

In csh:

```
if ($TERM == "xterm") then
  echo "Xterm display identified: echo enabled"
  set echo_disable = "0"
else
  set echo_disable = "1"
endif

# Use the following for all subsequent echo commands
if !( "$echo_disable" ) echo "Safe to display on Xterm"
```

It's a bit brute force, but it does work.

Comment: I tried using the [ "$SSH_TTY" ] code above and found that it only worked for simple client programs like putty. When I use NoMachine it doesn't provide any output. This is why I needed to include "xterm-256color" in the code above.

Comment: Interestingly enough, using "if ( $?SSH_TTY ) then" also did not work for my csh VM. I checked and there is no SSH_TTY environment variable defined. So my code above may be helpful to others that have a similar situation.