# Run a script in /etc/motd

Tags: unix, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to run a python script when people log in to the server. I thought editing /etc/motd would be the best approach, but since it's only readable file, that won't work.

I found pretty much identical post: [Is it possible to put commands in /etc/motd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/459229/)

What would be the best solution here? I'd like to run a script that shows the overview of the server, so the users would see the status immediately.

This was suggested `A useful practice is to put the command you want to be executed in a script named /etc/motd.sh and call this script from /etc/profile, usually at about the end of it.`

but received this comment `Putting output like a MOTD in your profile is likely to break sftp.`

Any solution will do. Thanks in advance

Comment: I did link that myself already in the post?:)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's better to use /etc/profile.d for this option. And source script there. It would display output on every login.

About the second problem and breakinf sftp. I did a little bit googling.

You can use:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Or add

```
if [ "$SSH_TTY" ]
then
   source .bashc_real
fi
```

to your script which prints motd-like message. I get this answer from([Use .bashrc without breaking sftp](https://serverfault.com/questions/485487/use-bashrc-without-breaking-sftp)).

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu/Debian, PAM module [pam_motd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_motd.8.html) supports that dynamic motd functionality, and supposedly it doesn't interfere with sftp.  Unfortunately it's not well documented.  You can instead consult [update-motd manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/update-motd.5.html) in Ubuntu.

On the Ubuntu systems you already have several scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/`.  They are live examples suitable for your own to start from.

Consider carefully about consuming certain resources on every login with dynamic motd.  Read *Best Practices* section in update-motd manpage.